# Why is this while loop infinite?

Tags: java

```
int MATCH_LENGTH = 0;
int FINAL_MATCH_LENGTH = 0;
int FINAL_MATCH_POS = 0;

while (window.contains(next)) {
    int MATCH_POS = window.indexOf(next);
    boolean nextMatches = true;
    while (nextMatches = true) {
        int index = window.indexOf(next);
        index++;
        int positionOfNext = fileArray.indexOf(next);
        positionOfNext++;
        MATCH_LENGTH++;
        char afterNext = fileArray.get(positionOfNext);
        char afterNextInWindow = window.get(index);
        if (afterNext != afterNextInWindow) {
            nextMatches = false;
            if (MATCH_LENGTH > FINAL_MATCH_LENGTH) {
                FINAL_MATCH_POS = MATCH_POS;
                FINAL_MATCH_LENGTH = MATCH_LENGTH;
                MATCH_LENGTH = 0;
            }
            window.remove(window.indexOf(next));
        }
    }
}
```

I am running into an infinite loop here. I think it is because of the `nextMatches` boolean variable. However, I am not sure how that affects the program, as I have the condition for the `while` loop as `while (window.contains(next))`. However, I am removing the occurrences of `next` one by one, so eventually `while (window.contains(next))` will have to return false and the `while` loop will have to break. My reasoning here might be flawed though with the remove line `window.remove(window.indexOf(next));`.

Or is some other part of my reasoning flawed?

Comment: whats window? you never clarify

Comment: `window` is a <Character> array of length 30, `fileArray` is a <Character> array. I copy out arrays of `window.size()` length from `fileArray` to make `window` arrays.

Comment: Do you mean arraylist? char[] has no method indexOf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here  `while (nextMatches = true)` try put instead

```
while (nextMatches == true)
```

Comment: I remove that text, because you were answering without confidence. When you answer you should do it with confidence, if you are wrong people will warn you.

Answer (score 7):

You made the classic `=` vs `==` mistake

```
while (nextMatches = true)
```

should be

```
while(nextMatches)
```

As a general rule, **don't compare booleans to `true` and `false`**. It just leads to these sort of weird bugs and makes the code less legible in my opinion. If you name your variables properly, Java conventions has booleans sound like a conditional. For example: `isEmpty` or `isFull`. This way things read like english: `while(isFull)`

I'm a bit confused on your logic, especially since `int index = window.indexof(next)` will not change anything. index will be redefined.

Comment: Just don't slap yourself `while (faceDoesntHurt = true)`

Comment: Wait, but I swapped `=` for `==` and the loop is still infinite.

Comment: Its ok we've all been there ;-)

Comment: I **made the necessary changes** and the loop is **still infinite.**

Comment: @user1744094 Because this condition if (afterNext != afterNextInWindow) is never true.

Comment: Updated fillling characters

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It was this line: `int index = window.indexOf(next);`.
I kept on redefining `index` as the same number over and over again, which caused the infinite loop. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

```
while (nextMatches == true) {
```

This condition will be `false` iff `nextMatches` is assigned with `false`.

The only place you are assigning it `false`, is in following code block:

```
if (afterNext != afterNextInWindow) {
    nextMatches = false;
    ...
```

Since, `while` is running infinite for you, it means `nextMatches` is never assigned with `false` when code executes, i.e **`if` condition is always `false`**.

This means, that in every iteration of `while`; `afterNext` is always equals to `afterNextInWindow`.